# How to open the phone call app with a given phone number to call?

Tags: iphone

I have an contacts management app where I have phone numbers stored in core data. These are represented simply as text, like `+33(0)7324 65335-22`. Is it possible to call this number by launching the phone app? And if yes, must I do special formatting to my number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"+33(0)7324 65335-22";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber]]];
```

I'm not sure about the "(0)"...

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: this is just UIApplication opening an URL. for the full list of available prefixes for different functions, check this out: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html